# Calculating average of preceeding and following values for NAs in a column in R

Tags: r, average, na

I have a data set that has measured values in some samples and leaves NAs in others.  In between each measured value is 10 samples with no value.  I want the value of those ten samples to each be the average of the proceeding and following measured values.  The data looks like this:

[image: data]

Importantly, the values for each of the ten NAs between any two known values has to be the same.  I previously tried using zoo::na.approx(RC, rule=2), but that calculates averages using its own interpolated data, not just the two known values.  The output should look like this:

[image]

Edit as per deschen's request:

> dput(rc_report[,c(2,26)])
> structure(list(sample_id = c("REFTTO_IS_211201_1_b", "ARL2108200_b",
> "ARL2108201_b", "ARL2108202_b", "ARL2108203_b", "ARL2108204_b",
> "ARL2108205_b", "ARL2108206_b", "ARL2108207_b", "ARL2108208_b",
> "ARL2108209_b", "REFTTO_IS_211201_2", "ARL2108210_b", "ARL2108211_b",
> "ARL2108212_b", "ARL2108213_b", "ARL2108214_b", "ARL2108215_b",
> "ARL2108216_b", "ARL2108217_b", "ARL2108218_b", "ARL2108219_b",
> "REFTTO_IS_211201_3", "REFTTO_IS_211203_1", "ARL2108220", "ARL2108221",
> "ARL2108222", "ARL2108223", "ARL2108224", "ARL2108225", "ARL2108226",
> "ARL2108227", "ARL2108228", "ARL2108229", "REFTTO_IS_211203_2",
> "ARL2108230", "ARL2108231", "ARL2108232", "ARL2108233", "ARL2108234",
> "ARL2108235", "ARL2108236", "ARL2108237", "ARL2108238", "ARL2108239",
> "REFTTO_IS_211203_3", "REFTTO_IS_211206_1", "ARL2108240", "ARL2108241",
> "ARL2108242", "ARL2108243", "ARL2108244", "ARL2108245", "ARL2108246",
> "ARL2108247", "ARL2108248", "ARL2108249", "REFTTO_IS_211206_2",
> "ARL2108250", "ARL2108251", "ARL2108252", "ARL2108253", "ARL2108254",
> "ARL2108255", "ARL2108256", "ARL2108258", "ARL2108259", "REFTTO_IS_211206_3"
> ), response_coefficient = c("1.09785865302384", "NA", "NA", "NA",
> "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "1.09822862814289",
> "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "1.09835314677401",
> "1.09942926690693", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA",
> "NA", "NA", "NA", "1.10084276861106", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA",
> "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "1.10078178211056", "1.11104600880183",
> "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "1.11203467893562",
> "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "1.11344223852824"
> )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -68L))

Comment: Please share: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, not images! Easiest would be to share the result of `dput(rc_report[, c(2, 26)]`.

Comment: Okay, I shared the dput result, but it's pretty unreadable, not sure how that will help.  I've tried many times to use reprex for this but I can never make it work, hence why I share screen shots.

Comment: the point isn't readability. The point is that anyone wanting to use it would have to retype the whole thing if the question omits it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using the following code.  It's probably pretty inefficient, but it does the job.

[image]

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and note where it states NOT to use images.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data shown in the Note at the end (we changed the column names to shorter ones) use na.locf0 both forwards and backwards taking the average.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

dd %>%
  mutate(coef = as.numeric(ifelse(coef == "NA", NA, coef)),
         coef = (na.locf0(coef) + na.locf0(coef, fromLast = TRUE)) / 2)
```

### Note

```
dd <- structure(list(sample_id = c("REFTTO_IS_211201_1_b", "ARL2108200_b", "ARL2108201_b", "ARL2108202_b", "ARL2108203_b", "ARL2108204_b", "ARL2108205_b", "ARL2108206_b", "ARL2108207_b", "ARL2108208_b", "ARL2108209_b", "REFTTO_IS_211201_2", "ARL2108210_b", "ARL2108211_b", "ARL2108212_b", "ARL2108213_b", "ARL2108214_b", "ARL2108215_b", "ARL2108216_b", "ARL2108217_b", "ARL2108218_b", "ARL2108219_b", "REFTTO_IS_211201_3", "REFTTO_IS_211203_1", "ARL2108220", "ARL2108221", "ARL2108222", "ARL2108223", "ARL2108224", "ARL2108225", "ARL2108226", "ARL2108227", "ARL2108228", "ARL2108229", "REFTTO_IS_211203_2", "ARL2108230", "ARL2108231", "ARL2108232", "ARL2108233", "ARL2108234", "ARL2108235", "ARL2108236", "ARL2108237", "ARL2108238", "ARL2108239", "REFTTO_IS_211203_3", "REFTTO_IS_211206_1", "ARL2108240", "ARL2108241", "ARL2108242", "ARL2108243", "ARL2108244", "ARL2108245", "ARL2108246", "ARL2108247", "ARL2108248", "ARL2108249", "REFTTO_IS_211206_2", "ARL2108250", "ARL2108251", "ARL2108252", "ARL2108253", 
"ARL2108254", "ARL2108255", "ARL2108256", "ARL2108258", "ARL2108259", "REFTTO_IS_211206_3" ), 
response_coefficient = c("1.09785865302384", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "1.09822862814289", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "1.09835314677401", "1.09942926690693", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"1.10084276861106", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "1.10078178211056", "1.11104600880183", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "1.11203467893562", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "1.11344223852824" )), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -68L))
names(dd) <- c("id", "coef")
```